# Given W(t) as a standard Wiener process, how do I plot $t \, W(1)$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$?

Tags: plotting, markov-process

I've plotted $W(t)$ using

```
timestep = 1/250
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, timestep}]
ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

Now I need to plot $W(t)$, $-t\, W(1)$, and $W(t) - t\, W(1)$ all in a single chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `"Properties"` of the generated `"TemporalData"` object:

```
timestep = 1./250;
W = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0., 1., timestep}]
ListLinePlot[
 {
  Transpose[{W["Times"], W["Values"]}],
  Transpose[{W["Times"], -W["Times"] W["Values"][[-1]]}],
  Transpose[{W["Times"], W["Values"] - W["Times"] W["Values"][[-1]]}]
  },
 Filling -> Axis
 ]
```

To see the list of all supported properties, just evaluate `W["Properties"]`.